# Sandboxing Publicly Accessible GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, network-security

I want to add a feature to a linux-based web service that allows untrusted users to upload the source code to a small C++ program, and for that code to be automatically saved to a file on the server and compiled with gcc and then executed, capturing the standard output.  (This is a feature not unlike ideone.com, or spoj.pl, or topcoder.com, or codechef.com, or many of other web sites that do this.)

My questions are:

Q1. How do I sandbox the executable to guard against malicous users that try to damage the filesystem or access the network, etc?

Q2. Is there a fair/accurate way of rashoning system resources to the process, such as processor time and memory usage?

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you are going to downvote than leave a comment please.

Comment: This is more of an administration question.  You may want to ask the http://serverfault.com/ community.

Comment: @Tom Kerr: It turns out that a programming solution is required.

Comment: @Joshua Yah, looks like it.  I'd think chroot and all that would have been appropriate for them.  I'd think they'd be able to tell you what they *could* do at least, so you didn't reinvent any wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. chroot jail
2. ulimit
3. patch kernel so socket() by the uid you are running this as fails.

Comment: And put the machine well out of reach of your private data and network. And put together some quick recovery scheme to get it up and running when it inevitably gets compromised. And probably don't bother. The compiler is really, really not designed to be secure.

Comment: that's why you run the compiler as the jailed user

Comment: You don't need to patch the kernel. It's sufficient to link a stub libc before the real one, and make `socket` a nop in that stub library. But you'll need to stub a few more, such as `syscall`.

Comment: @MSalters none of that stops the user calling syscalls manually. That's why Joshua suggests patching the kernel.

Comment: @ams: can you clarify how that would be done? If the compiler turns `syscall(0)` into `(void)(0)`, executing the result won't reach into the kernel. There's no "manual" way to make a syscall; you're only executing the compiler output, linked against a fixed set of libraries. (You probably shouldn't have `as` , the assembler, in the chroot jail)

Comment: @MSalters: Of course you can make syscalls manually: you can use asm inserts (just like `syscall` does) or there always good old fashioned buffer overrun attacks (etc.) on the compiler itself. A syscall just requires loading a few magic numbers and parameters into registers, and then calling a magic instruction; on x86 the instruction is `int 80`, I think, but each architecture has some variation on the raise-an-exception theme to do kernel calls. They're not magic: there's nothing special about the C library that makes it work.

Comment: @MSalters: re your point about not including `as`: the OP want to execute the compiled code on the server. That means `as` is necessary. (It also kinda makes the security of the compiler a moot point.)

Comment: @MSalters: wow that was ignorant. I can cast a pointer to a byte array to a function pointer and call it. Direct invocation of as isn't even required.

Comment: @Joshua: I was assuming NX functionality. Isn't that a given nowadays, certainly for such sandboxes?