# How to compile and execute c++ program safely with security restrictions?

Tags: c++, security, compilation

I am looking for a way to compile and execute c++ program in a folder such that it will not have access to other folders or programs outside the folder in which it is being executed. I am trying to build an online c++ compiler.

Things I want to avoid from a program is to access any file outside the folder, change/ delete any file or create new files and copy at a new location. All to save the server from malicious code being executed and bringing the system down.

I have a windows environment but if there is a better way to achieve then linux would do well. I have looked for user roles in windows, access permissions and some 3d party apps like sandboxy as well, but not convinced with any of it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be giving people this locked and loaded gun? If you don't truly understand all the security issues, you may be asking for a world of hurt.

Comment: I am trying to understand security issues, it will be  good learning lesson even though i can not implement it fully.

Comment: Some things here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827551/sandboxing-publicly-accessible-gcc

Answer (score 2):

`chroot` is used for this on on *nix systems, but make sure you also run the code as a user with sufficiently restricted privileges to stop them just undoing the chroot: http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot

For Windows equivalent: https://serverfault.com/questions/161507/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-chroot, although it doesn't look as though that question got a huge amount of attention.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I guess not many people will be interested in similar stuffhave gone through sandboxie details. I do not want to risk using any 3rd party cause have had bad experiences when 3rd parties change their policy and you have your core part depending upon it.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply a system-wide permission assigned to the users which let them only to read/write/execute only inside a specific folder. so he/she can't access outside world nor create files/folders, etc.

Comment: The compiler has to run under that account as well. You wouldn't want users to do a `#include </etc/passwd>`